# What is PHP's each() function useful for?

Tags: php

What do people use the `each($array)` for?

http://theserverpages.com/php/manual/en/function.each.php

Comment: you shouldn't end a sentence in a proposition. :)

Comment: @nathan [Nonsense](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16/when-is-it-okay-to-end-a-sentence-in-a-preposition/47#47)

Comment: @Michael, well crap.  head = exploded.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Nothing, now that `foreach()` exists.

Comment: `foreach` uses a copy, whereas `each()` works on the array itself. If you manipulate the array pointer within the loop, it will affect the loop. With `foreach` this isn't possible.

Comment: you don't see so often a 100k answering you

Comment: @KingCrunch actually... "As of PHP 5, you can easily modify array's elements by preceding $value with &. This will assign reference instead of copying the value."

Comment: @onteria_: That refers to changing the values within the array, whereas @KingCrunch is talking about walking along the array itself. Which is insane in its own right, but that's neither here nor there.

Answer (score 5):

According to [PHP's documentation](http://us.php.net/each):

> each() is typically used in conjunction with list() to traverse an array.

```
<?php
$fruit = array('a' => 'apple', 'b' => 'banana', 'c' => 'cranberry');

reset($fruit);
while (list($key, $val) = each($fruit)) {
    echo "$key => $val\n";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I imagine it was from PHP 3, which did not support `foreach`, and was preserved in later versions for compatibility. For example:

```
for(;$x=each($myArray),$key=$x['key'],$value=$x['value'];) {
    // do something
}
```

Would be the closest thing to a `foreach` loop.